# Are extendible cardinals $\Sigma_3$-reflective, choicelessly?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, large-cardinals

> **Definition.** A cardinal $\kappa$ is extendible if for each $\alpha$ there is $\zeta$ and $j:V_{\kappa+\alpha}\prec V_\zeta$ and $\operatorname{crit}j=\kappa$, $j(\kappa)>\alpha$.

*(There was confusion about the definition of extendible cardinals. See @Farmer S's comment or my comment below on my question.)*

It is well-known that extendible cardinals are $\Sigma_3$-reflective:

> *Proof.* ($\mathsf{ZFC}$)
> Let $\phi(x,y)$ be a $\Pi_2$ formula and $a\in V_\kappa$. In one direction, if $V_\kappa \models \exists x\phi(x,a)$, then $V_\kappa\models \phi(x,a)$ for some $x$, so $V\models \phi(x,a)$ since $\kappa$ is supercompact and every supercompact cardinals are $\Sigma_2$-reflecting.
>
> For the other direction, assume that $V\models \phi(x,a)$ for some $x$. Take $\alpha>\operatorname{rank} x$ and $j:V_{\kappa+\alpha}\prec V_\zeta$, $\operatorname{crit}j=\kappa$ and $j(\kappa)>\alpha$. Then $V_\kappa\prec V_{j(\kappa)}$ and $j(\kappa)$ is inaccessible. Since $H_{j(\kappa)}=V_{j(\kappa)}$ and *by the Levy absoluteness theorem, $V_{j(\kappa)}\models \phi(x,a)$*. Hence $V_\kappa\models \exists x\phi(x,a)$.

The standard proof (given above) uses the Levy absoluteness theorem, whose proof uses the axiom of choice. I can see that $\mathsf{ZF}$ still proves extendible cardinals are $\Sigma_2$-reflecting, essentially by the above argument. (It requires $\Sigma_1$-reflection of supercompactness, which follows from Magidor-like characterization of supercompactness over $\mathsf{ZF}$.)

> **Question.** Can we prove extendible cardinals are $\Sigma_3$-reflecting from $\mathsf{ZF}$?

I think the following question is relevant to the above one:

> **Question.** ($\mathsf{ZF}$) If $\kappa$ is inaccessible, then $V_\kappa\prec_{\Sigma_1} V$?

---

$\Sigma_3$-reflection property of extendible are referred to papers about choiceless large cardinals (e.g., [Bagaria-Koellner-Woodin](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-symbolic-logic/article/abs/large-cardinals-beyond-choice/5AF5AF52A795AB3CCAAA1381B0C868C3), or [Cutolo's doctoral thesis](http://www.fedoa.unina.it/11570/1/cutolo_raffaella_29.pdf).) They use $\Sigma_3$-reflection of extendibles to establish the relation between extendible cardinals and Berkely cardinals, although I think we can avoid $\Sigma_3$-reflection for proving these results.

---

*Note.* I was missed that Bagaria-Koellner-Woodin uses a slightly different definition for extendible cardinals. (They called the usual extendibles as *weakly extendibles*. However, Cutolo used the same definition as that of mine.) Here is the definition given by Bagaria-Koellner-Woodin:

> **Definition.** A cardinal $\kappa$ is *extendible* if for each $\alpha$ there is $\alpha'$ and $j:V_{\kappa+\alpha}\prec V_{j(\kappa)+\alpha'}$ such that $\operatorname{crit}j=\kappa$, $\alpha<j(\kappa)$ and for each $\beta<\alpha$, $j(A\cap V_{\kappa+\beta})=A\cap V_{j(\kappa)+j(\beta)}$, where
> $$A = \{\gamma \mid V_{\gamma}\prec_{\Sigma_1^*} V\}.$$

Note that, $V_{\gamma}\prec_{\Sigma_1^*} V$ if and only if for every $\alpha<\gamma$, a $\Delta_0$-formula $\phi(x,y)$, and $a\in V_\gamma$, if $$\exists b \,[{^{V_\alpha}}\,b\subseteq b\mathrel{\land} \phi(a,b)]$$
then
$$\exists b \in V_\gamma \,[{^{V_\alpha}}\,b\subseteq b\mathrel{\land} \phi(a,b)]$$

Comment: There's some subtlety here. For example, there are a few inequivalent definitions of inaccessibility in the absence of choice (mostly variations on "strong limit"); also, as it's relevant for Levy absoluteness, there are a few different definitions of $H_\kappa$ as well.

Comment: @Jason I assumed an inaccessible as a cardinal $\kappa$ such that $V_\kappa$ is a model of second-order $\mathsf{ZF}$. I have no clear idea for $H_\kappa$, but my hunch is that a 'correct' choiceless argument should avoid any $H_\kappa$ (if it exists.)

Comment: In the version of the Bagaria-Koellner-Woodin paper I’m looking at just now (I think it’s a preprint), they define “extendible” differently to this, and “weakly extendible” as you defined “extendible”.

Comment: @FarmerS Thank you, I missed this point.

Comment: No worries. Still, I think both your questions (using the definition of extendible you were using for the first) are good.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of supercompactness given by Bagaria-Koellner-Woodin allows $\Sigma_2$- and $\Sigma_3$-reflection, respectively. It does not answer my original question but solves some non-trivial parts of their paper.

Let me sketch how to prove it. First, we can see that extendible cardinals are supercompact. Moreover,

> **Claim.** If $\kappa$ is supercompact, then $V_\kappa\prec_{\Sigma_2}V$.
>
> *Proof.* Let $a\in V_\kappa$ and $\phi(x,y)$ be a $\Pi_1$-formula.
>
> For one direction, assume that $V\models \forall x\lnot\phi(x,a)$. Then $\forall x\in V_\kappa \lnot\phi(x,a)$. By supercompactness, we can find $\overline{\gamma}<\kappa$ such that $a\in V_{\overline{\gamma}}$ and $V_{\overline{\gamma}}\prec_{\Sigma_1^*} V$. Hence $\forall x\in  V_\kappa (V_{\overline{\gamma}}\models \lnot\phi(x,a))$. The rest is straightforward.
>
> (Note that the existence of the above $\overline{\gamma}$ does not directly follow from the definition of supercompactness, since we need an additional condition that $\overline{\gamma}$ can be arbitrarily large below $\kappa$. I think modifying the proof of Lemma 222 of Woodin's *Suitable Extender models I* would work. In fact, I also think that the critical point of $j: V_{\overline{\gamma}}\to V_\gamma$ can be arbitrarily large below $\kappa$.)
>
> For the other direction, assume that $V\models\exists x\phi(x,a)$ holds. Take $\gamma$ such that $b\in V_\gamma\prec_{\Sigma_1^*} V$ for $b$ such that $\phi(b,a)$. By supercompactness, we can find $j:V_{\overline{\gamma}}\to V_\gamma$ such that $\operatorname{crit}j > \operatorname{rank} a$ and $V_\overline{\gamma}\prec_{\Sigma_1^*} V$.
> The rest is direct from $V_\gamma\models \exists x \phi(x,a)$.

Now we have

> **Theorem.** If $\kappa$ is extendible, then $V_\kappa\prec_{\Sigma_3}V$.
>
> *Proof.* Let $a\in V_\kappa$ and $\phi(x,y)$ be a $\Pi_2$-formula. We only prove the non-trivial direction.
>
> Assume that $V\models \phi(b,a)$ for some $b$. Observe that if $\kappa$ is supercompact, then $A = \{\xi \mid V_{\xi}\prec_{\Sigma_1^*} V\}$ is cofinal below $\kappa$, so $V_\kappa\prec_{\Sigma_1^*} V$. (We are using that $A$ is closed under arbitrary unions.)
>
> Take large $\alpha\in A$ such that $V_\alpha \prec_{\Sigma_1^*} V $, $\kappa+\alpha=\alpha$ and $b\in V_\alpha$.
> By extendibility, there is $j:V_\alpha\to V_{\alpha'}$ such that $\operatorname{crit}j=\kappa$, $\alpha<j(\kappa)$ and for each $\beta<\alpha$, $j(A\cap V_{\kappa+\beta})=A\cap V_{j(\kappa)+j(\beta)}$. Since $V_\alpha\models (A\cap \kappa\text{ is cofinal below }\kappa)$, we have
> $$V_{\alpha'}\models A\cap j(\kappa) \text{ is cofinal below } j(\kappa),$$
> which implies $V_{j(\kappa)}\prec_{\Sigma_1^*}V$. Then we are done by mimicking the $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proof of $\Sigma_3$-reflection of extendibles.

Comment: About the second question part, is $\forall\alpha\in{\rm Lim}\, V_\alpha\models\sf AC$ really $\Pi_1$? It looks like $\Pi_2$ to me.

Comment: @Asaf Yes, you are right. Then the last question is still open.